# Writing std::string to REG_MULTI_SZ registry

Tags: c++, registry

I'm programming in C++. How to set a value, which is `std::string` type, to registry `REG_MULTI_SZ`? I read a lot of examples, but I only found about writing `DWORD` or `REG_SZ`. I'm not able to find what I need there.

Here's what I have so far:

```
std::string value; 
DWORD dwTypeMulti, dwSize; 
dwTypeMulti = REG_MULTI_SZ; 
dwSize = sizeof(DWORD); 
RegSetValueEx(hkey, TEXT("MyValue1"), 0, dwTypeMulti, (LPBYTE)&value, dwSize);
```

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong? *With the REG_MULTI_SZ data type, the string must be terminated with two null characters.* and *If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or REG_MULTI_SZ, cbData must include the size of the terminating null character or characters.* - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Don't post code-walls in comments. *Update your question*.

Comment: A REG_MULTI_SZ value looks like L"foo\0bar\0baz\0".  And is not 4 bytes long.

Comment: My string looks like e.g. 10.0.0.1, it's an IP address, so how it have to be like? :) 10\0.0\0.0.1\0? ehh

Comment: I haven't tried it with this particular API, but the definition of multisz is not actually standardized.  The typical format of a multisz is, for example, L"str1\0str2\0" or 11 characters and the end of the WCHAR[] array is double null-terminated.

Comment: **However**,  many system APIs consider the length of the buffer and do not rely on the end to be double null-terminated.  For that style of multisz implementation, L"str1\0str2" (WCHAR[10]) is valid, and also L"str1" (WCHAR[4]) is valid because it is common to want to store a regular C string into a multisz.  So...value.c_str() should work for you.

Comment: **BTW**, when you write a loop to walk a multisz, it *should* handle the case where the array is only single null-terminated.  Although, you can generally count on the system to return multiszs double null terminated. https://samscode.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-safely-walk-multisz-string-list.html